# Partial deduction of template arguments in VS2013 for variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

The following fails to deduce template arguments in VS2013 with the following error,error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'f'.  However compiles fine GCC.

```
template <class TRAIT, class ...T>
void myVarFunc(T...arg)
{
    printf("test");
}

typedef void(*f)(int a, char b);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   f myf = &myVarFunc<int>;
   myf(1, 'x');
   return 0;
}
```

Can anyone determine why this fails, the same function can be instantiated using the following:

```
myVarFunc<int>(1, 'x');  //compiles ok
```

And the following also compiles:

```
template <class ...Args>
void myVarFunc(Args...arg)
{
    printf("test");
}

typedef void(*f)(int a, char b);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    f myf = myVarFunc;  //compiles ok
    myf(1, 'x');
    return 0;
}
```

So when adding an extra type to the template, it fails to deduce the parameters, could this be a compiler bug, or just not supported by the language?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like a bug of *vc 2013*. [Both *clang 3.5.0* and *gcc 4.9.0* compile this code fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5468a05ca5f5e7e) (with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors` flags).

Comment: The bug seems to be fixed in the upcoming Visual C++ 2015 - the code compiles and works fine in CTP6.